# Shop by brands on view page

Tags: attributes, configurable-product

I'm trying to make the functionality on my eCommerce web site, so the users can shop by brands. I'm trying to accomplish this without using any extension and the brands are suppose to be displayed on my view.phtml page.

What exactly I need to do is to tell the Magento, **if** one attribute (brand) is being used on view page, to **hide** (not to display) **ALL** other attributes (brands).

I have the following code, which I use.

```
<a class="acer-<?php echo $_product->getData("lp_brand"); ?>" title="Acer" href="http://www.domain.com/category?lp_brand=78"
<a/>

<a class="toshiba-<?php echo $_product->getData("lp_brand"); ?>" title="Toshiba" href="http://www.domain.com/categorylp_?brand=79"
<a/>

<a class="dell-<?php echo $_product->getData("lp_brand"); ?>" title="Dell" href="http://www.domain.com/category?lp_brand=80"
<a/>
```

Comment: so if `lp_brand` has a certain value it should display on one of the three above?

Answer (score 1):

I managed this by using CSS.

Below is my code, which works fine:

**html**

```
<div class="product-brand">
<a title="Acer" href="http://www.domain.com/category?lp_brand=<?php    echo $_product->getData("lp_brand"); ?>">
<span class="brand-<?php echo $_product->getData("lp_brand"); ?>">
<?php echo $_product->getData("lp_brand"); ?>
</span>
</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.brand-76 {
    background-image: url("http://www.domain.com/assets/images/acer-logo.png");
    background-position: 23px -72px;
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    text-indent: -99999px;
}
```

Comment: Please add some details to make the answer useful

Comment: hi, i edited my question with the solution provided within!

Comment: Great, I moved it to the answer